# Como leer subelementos en PSEINT

Tags: pseint

Hola buenas tardes quisiera poder saber como puede hacer para mostrar los subelementos de este arreglo, que el programa muestre en cada subarreglo la unidad , la decena y la centena

```
Algoritmo unidades
    //Ingrese un número de tres cifras y muestra la unidad, decena y la centena.
    Dimension arreglo[1]
    Escribir "Ingrese el numero: "
    Leer arreglo[1]
    
    Escribir arreglo[1]
    
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

Te ayudo con esto, pero te queda terminar que diga las unidades, decenas...

```
Algoritmo SeparaDigitos
    
    Escribir "Ingrese un numero: "
    Leer input
    digito <- 0
    Mientras input <> 0 Hacer
        Si input % 10 <> 0 Entonces
            digito <- input % 10
            Escribir digito
            input <- input - digito
        SiNo
            input <- input / 10
        Fin Si
    Fin Mientras

FinAlgoritmo
```